# How does the TensorFlow dataset handle large data that cannot fit into the memory in a server?

Tags: tensorflow

## Question

How does the TensorFlow dataset handle large data that cannot fit into the memory in a server?

Spark RDD can handle large large data with multiple nodes. For the question in [Tensorflow Transform: How to find the mean of a variable over the entire dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879198/tensorflow-transform-how-to-find-the-mean-of-a-variable-over-the-entire-dataset), the answer is using Tensorflow Transform which uses Apache Beam that requires a distributed computation cluster such as Spark.

> if we have large dataset, say a CSV file that is 50GB, then how do you calculate the mean or other similar statistics.

Hence I suppose TensorFlow requires a multi node cluster but not clear if TensorFlow has its own cluster implementation, or re-using existing technologies. Since TensorFlow pre-processing e.g. getting mean or std of a column requires Apache Beam, I guess it is Apache Beam based too, but not sure.

A google paper [Large-Scale Machine Learning on Heterogeneous Distributed Systems](https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/tensorflow-whitepaper2015.pdf) shows multiple workers.
[image]

This article [TensorFlow: A new paradigm for large scale ML in distributed systems](https://medium.com/coinmonks/tensorflow-a-new-paradigm-for-large-scale-ml-in-distributed-systems-fc45458e0c5) tells the system components.

> In terms of system components, TensorFlow consists of Master, Worker and Client for distributed coordination and execution.

This Github [TensorFlow2-tutorial/05-distributed-training/](https://github.com/lambdal/TensorFlow2-tutorial/tree/master/05-distributed-training) tells TF_CONFIG specifying the node IP/port.

```
TF_CONFIG='{"cluster": {"worker": ["10.1.10.58:12345", "10.1.10.250:12345"]}, "task": {"index": 0, "type": "worker"}}' python worker.py
```

TensorFlow example Github [Distributed TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/docs/deploy/distributed.md) has the section below but do not see node setup detail.

> Create a tf.train.ClusterSpec to describe the cluster

Hence apparently there is a way to setup TensorFlow cluster which I suppose handles large dataset loading into a TF dataset.

However, [Install TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) only shows:

```
# Current stable release for CPU and GPU
pip install tensorflow
```

Please point to the step by step documentation of how to setup a TensorFlow multi node cluster, and resources that explain the details on how the large data loading is handled (Similar to the Spark RDD/DataFrame explanation and internals) in TF.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use generator functions that pull in chunked data. Each chunk that took want to send is through a **yield ** operation. Tensorflow allows one to create a `Dataset` that returns Tensors as input yielded by a generator function. This dataset is finally viewed by the .fit methods as follows:

```py
import itertools

def gen():
  for i in itertools.count(1):
    yield (i, [1] * i)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     gen,
     (tf.int64, tf.int64),
     (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None])))

list(dataset.take(3).as_numpy_iterator())

train(dataset, max_steps=100)
```

This approach has several benefits:

- it limits the usage of RAM when training (to the size of chunks)
- it allows one to stream asynchronously (like from a large file, remote database, web scraping bot,  etc.)